# Python3: Sorting CSV file data from 4 columns to 2 columns

Tags: python-3.x

How can I sort my data from 4 columns to 2 columns

My data looks like this

```
Title,,,

Add User:,true,Start Date, 13-03-2018

Change User:,false,Date Required:,13-03-2018

Remove User:,false,Finish Date:,

Lock User Account:,false,Date of Birth:,""
```

Expected Result:

```
Title,
,
Add User:,true

Start Date, 13-03-2018

Change User:,false

Date Required:,13-03-2018

Remove User:,false

Finish Date:,
Lock User Account:,false

Date of Birth:,""
```

Comment: Sorting is applying some ordering mechanism. Reformatting 4 columns to 2 is not necessarily sorting. Describe more precisely what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very new to python, but i guess you can use regular expressions as below:

```
a = """Title,,,

Add User:,true,Start Date, 13-03-2018

Change User:,false,Date Required:,13-03-2018

Remove User:,false,Finish Date:,

Lock User Account:,false,Date of Birth:,"""

import re

re.sub("(^\\w+,)|(\\w:,[^,]+),","\\1\\2\n",re.sub("\\n\\n","\\n",a)).split("\n")
Out[291]: 
['Title,',
 ',,',
 'Add User:,true',
 'Start Date, 13-03-2018',
 'Change User:,false',
 'Date Required:,13-03-2018',
 'Remove User:',
 'false,Finish Date:,',
 'Lock User Account:',
 'false,Date of Birth:,']
```